# Creating a PDF viewer in XCode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode5, quartz-graphics, pdfview

I am new to XCode and Objective-C and am trying to create a multi-document PDF viewer using Cocoa. I am using the Quartz framework, but am not entirely sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to sample application provided by apple - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PDFAnnotationEditor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004035

Comment: How do you do things like open a PDF document from the Open menu (or via a button)? At the moment, I just have it hard-coded to open a specific PDF document. I want to be able to choose from my files which PDf document to open.

Comment: Create IBAction for your button or menu item and add following code  inside this -                                   "NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
        if(result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton){
            NSURL *url = [[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
            // Use above selected url to load pdf documents inside your application
        }
    }];"

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. How do I implement the multi-document functionality? I'm not sure how to go about doing this?

Comment: Sample app supports this functionality by default. No extra efforts required for this.